# Unexpected any when passing callback to third-party library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have some React+TypeScript code that makes use of a component from a third party library.

`<ThirdPartyComponent onSelect={(value: any) => {...}} />`

eslint-typescript is identifying this as an issue:

> Unexpected any. Specify a different type. eslint(@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any)

The type definition of the select handler uses `any`:

```
export interface ThirdPartySelectCallback extends React.EventHandler<any> {
  (value: any, e: React.SyntheticEvent<{}>): void;
}
```

What is the proper way to avoid this issue without disabling the eslint rule?

---

Changing the type to `string` gives a different error:

`<ThirdPartyComponent onSelect={(value: string, e: React.SyntheticEvent<{}>) => {...}} />`

> Type '(value: string, e: SyntheticEvent<{}, Event>) => void' is not assignable to type 'ThirdPartySelectCallback'

Comment: Can't you just assume the type you expect? Or is the item type random?

Comment: How about `onSelect={(value: string)` ? Or just add `// eslint:disable-line` because you cannot control a third party component

Comment: Assuming a narrower type gives a different error.  I updated the question with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ThirdPartyComponent` like this:

```
// add the 2nd parameter e?: React.SyntheticEvent<{}>
const App = () => (
  <ThirdPartyComponent
    onSelect={(v: string, e?: React.SyntheticEvent<{}>) => {}}
  />
)

const ThirdPartyComponent = (props: { onSelect: ThirdPartySelectCallback }) => (
  <div>Hello package</div>
)
```

#### Some explanation

`React.EventHandler<any>` as well as `ThirdPartySelectCallback` are  [function type interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types). When one function interface extends another, for each function parameter the union of the types is formed (because function types are [contravariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) in their parameters). Have a look at this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEZkG8BQzkAUcAXMgM5hSgDmAlKQG4D2wAJjgL446iSyIpUAJmQQAHpBCsyaTLnxFSIAK4BbAEbQANMnWkKVEHUYt2XHAiYgKyYENLDkAXkIlylGsgA+yFRu26APz6Hka0zgB82BxAA) for an easy example of this merging.

So let's take your example again:

```
// React.EventHandler - eased up a bit here
type EventHandler<E extends SyntheticEvent<any>> = (event: E): void 

interface ThirdPartySelectCallback extends React.EventHandler<any> {
  (value: any, e: React.SyntheticEvent<{}>): void;
}
```

- First parameters are `E` and `any`. `E` | `any` becomes effectively `any`.
- Second parameters are `undefined` (first function has no second parameter) and `React.SyntheticEvent<{}>`, so its merged to `React.SyntheticEvent<{}> | undefined`.

So in the end, you can specify the following function for `ThirdPartySelectCallback`:

```
(v: any, e?: React.SyntheticEvent<{}>) => void
```

, where `v` can be literally of any type like `string` to solve your eslint error.